# Is there a way to limit an integer value to a certain range without branching?

Tags: c++, mips, branchless

Just out of curiosity. If I have something like:

```
if(x < 0)
    x = 0;
if(x > some_maximum)
    x = some_maximum;

return x;
```

Is there a way to not branch? This is c++.

Addendum: I mean no branch instructions in the assembly. It's a MIPS architecture.

Comment: I think he pretty obviously means "without branching in the executable", not "without using `if` statements"

Comment: I don't find it obvious, the term is used in more than one context. Well, i'm happy to delete my answer if its clarified.

Comment: Just a note, if this is for production, what you have is about as good as you'll get, especially in terms of readability (which is usually much more important than a couple cpu instructions). Of course, if the question is for more curiosity purposes, then it seems a lot more relevant. After all, computer scientists are the kings of "Why did you do it that way?" "Because we can!"

Comment: BTW, what is x?  int? float? class foo?

Comment: Have you tried compiling the code you have (possibly experimenting with different optimization flags) and checking what instructions get emitted?  Depending on your compiler and CPU architecture, you may not have to change any code at all.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are bit-tricks to find the minimum or maximum of two numbers, so you could use those to find `min(max(x, 0), some_maximum)`. From [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax):

```
y ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y)); // min(x, y)
x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y)); // max(x, y)
```

As the source states though, it's probably faster to do it the normal way, despite the branch

Comment: Well, perhaps not completely answering the question: "On some machines, evaluating (x < y) as 0 or 1 requires a branch instruction". Also I note that the site describes the obvious approach (using a ternary operator) as possibly faster depending on the target architecture...

Answer (score 13):

This is going to be compiler- and processor-dependent, but if you use `?:` it can be translated to a conditional move (at least on Intel-based processors) which does not use a branch.

`x = x < 0 ? 0 : x;
 x = x > max ? max : x;`

This can use the `CMOV` instruction (see http://www.intel.com/software/products/documentation/vlin/mergedprojects/analyzer_ec/mergedprojects/reference_olh/mergedProjects/instructions/instruct32_hh/vc35.htm), whose purpose is to avoid branching (and thus branch prediction penalties).

**Edit**: this [thread](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/tamarin-devel/2008-April/000455.html) may be of interest to you.  Benchmarks show that conditional moves will give you speed gains only on branches that are not very predictable, whereas highly predictable branches (such as that of a long-running loop) prefer the standard approach.

Comment: (Why) Can't the original code also be compiled to use CMOV? Assuming `x` is not volatile, of course.

Comment: ... Actually, GCC with -O4 seems determined (with the OP's code and x an int) to use a cmovge for one of the limits, and a branch for the other. With your code they're both cmovs. Don't know why.

Answer (score 10):

In C++17 you can use [`std::clamp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp)

> Defined in header `<algorithm>`
>
> ```
> template<class T>
> constexpr const T& clamp( const T& v, const T& lo, const T& hi );   (1)   (since C++17)
> template<class T, class Compare>
> constexpr const T& clamp( const T& v, const T& lo, const T& hi, Compare comp );    (2)    (since C++17)
> ```
>
> 1. If v compares less than lo, returns lo; otherwise if hi compares
>      less than v, returns hi; otherwise returns v. Uses operator< to
>      compare the values.
> 2. Same as (1), but uses comp to compare the values.

Comment: And this is worth mentioning that because it is `constexpr` it can be evaluated at compile time.
So it should fit the OP _no branch instructions in the assembly_ requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Using the ternary operator :)

```
return x < 0 ? 0 : x > some_maximum ? : some_maximum : x;
```

Comment: That will still cause branch instructions to show up in the executable if the architecture doesn't support a non-branching way to do it, right?

Comment: @Carl Norum: yes, but it's his best shot (see my answer for more details).

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your architecture.  For ARM, at least, the compiler would probably emit conditionally executed instructions and the resulting machine code wouldn't contain a branch.  I can't think of a good way to make that explicit in the C program though.

Comment: Unless ARM's conditional instructions are much different from those used by Intel processors, it is my understanding that a `?:` is explicitly required for translation to conditional moves.

Comment: ARM is much different than intel - it will use conditional run opcodes on any compare to prevent branching.

Comment: @Michael Dorgan: this would still depend on the compiler, wouldn't it?

Comment: Conditional executed opcodes are the bread and butter of the ARM architecture.  They were designed to prevent just this sort of branching.  While I guess there is a possibility of finding a compiler that won't do this, it would be a very, VERY poor compiler.

Comment: @danben: Of course, it depends on the compiler. Any compiler is entitled to emit arbitrarily awful code. But given the way ARM's conditional opcodes are designed, a "good" ARM compiler will use them in preference to a conditional branch over a short run of code.

Answer (score 2):

For future problems like this, the bit hack page might be useful: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html.

Since the bithack for min and max was already posted, here is a different one:

```
// CHAR_BIT is number of bits per byte.
// sign = 1 if x < 0, sign = 0 otherwise (according to the page above)
int sign = (int)((unsigned int)((int)x) >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1));

int y = (1-sign)*x; // if x < 0, then y = 0, else y = x.

// Depending on arch, the below _might_ cause a branch.
// (on x64 it does not cause a branch, not sure about MIPS)

int z = !(y/some_maximum); // if 0 <= y < some_maximum, z = 1, else z = 0

int ret = z*y + (1-z)*some_maximum; // if z =1, then ret = y; else ret = some_maximum.

return ret;
```

I just tried it out, and it worked for the few test cases i had.

Here is the assembly code from my computer (intel arch) which shows no branches.

```
int cap(int x)
{
00F013A0  push        ebp  
00F013A1  mov         ebp,esp 
00F013A3  sub         esp,0FCh 
00F013A9  push        ebx  
00F013AA  push        esi  
00F013AB  push        edi  
00F013AC  lea         edi,[ebp-0FCh] 
00F013B2  mov         ecx,3Fh 
00F013B7  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh 
00F013BC  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi] 

    int some_maximum = 100;

00F013BE  mov         dword ptr [some_maximum],64h 

    // CHAR_BIT is number of bits per byte. 
    // sign = 1 if x < 0, sign = 0 otherwise (according to the page above) 
    int sign = (int)((unsigned int)((int)x) >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)); 

00F013C5  mov         eax,dword ptr [x] 
00F013C8  shr         eax,1Fh 
00F013CB  mov         dword ptr [sign],eax 

    int y = (1-sign)*x; // if x < 0, then y = 0, else y = x. 

00F013CE  mov         eax,1 
00F013D3  sub         eax,dword ptr [sign] 
00F013D6  imul        eax,dword ptr [x] 
00F013DA  mov         dword ptr [y],eax 

    // Depending on arch, the below _might_ cause a branch. 
    // (on x64 it does not cause a branch, not sure about MIPS) 

    int z = !(y/some_maximum); // if 0 <= y < some_maximum, z = 1, else z = 0 

00F013DD  mov         eax,dword ptr [y] 
00F013E0  cdq              
00F013E1  idiv        eax,dword ptr [some_maximum] 
00F013E4  neg         eax  
00F013E6  sbb         eax,eax 
00F013E8  add         eax,1 
00F013EB  mov         dword ptr [z],eax 

    int ret = z*y + (1-z)*some_maximum; // if z =1, then ret = y; else ret = some_maximum. 

00F013EE  mov         eax,dword ptr [z] 
00F013F1  imul        eax,dword ptr [y] 
00F013F5  mov         ecx,1 
00F013FA  sub         ecx,dword ptr [z] 
00F013FD  imul        ecx,dword ptr [some_maximum] 
00F01401  add         eax,ecx 
00F01403  mov         dword ptr [ret],eax 

    return ret; 

00F01406  mov         eax,dword ptr [ret] 
}
00F01409  pop         edi  
00F0140A  pop         esi  
00F0140B  pop         ebx  
00F0140C  mov         esp,ebp 
00F0140E  pop         ebp  
00F0140F  ret
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible to limit to powers of 2 (non inclusive), then just go with

`int newx = x & ((highest power of 2) - 1)`

not quite sure to handle the (if x < 0 case) or the generic (x < n case)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = min(max(x,0),100);
```

The branching is hidden away nicely inside functions with normal names.

Suggesting to create a clip_by template.

Comment: Hiding it away is not the same as not doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
x =   ((int)(x > some_maximum)) * some_maximum 
    + ((int)(x > 0 && x <= some_maximum)) * x;
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the top of the range or the fact that `some_maximum` is a constant value.  (Likely you are taking `some_maximum` as the value to restrict).

Comment: That always loses the original value of x.